# Can I solicit investments in a private Facebook group?

Tags: business, israel, investment

I was told that soliciting investments for my business in public without registering at the bursa is illegal.

Is it legal to solicit investment in a closed/private Facebook group? Is a private group public?

I am in Israel. The business is international.

Comment: I don't think "bursa" is the right word there, what are you saying you need to register at?

Comment: @RonBeyer "Stock Exchange in Israel": http://www.isa.gov.il/sites/ISAEng/1489/1511/Pages/Section-49A-to-the-Securities-Law.aspx